# Select columns with fread based on both index and column names

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, fread

I'm trying to read a file with `fread`, and select columns based on **both** index and column names. I can do this with `dplyr` but cannot with `data.table`. Just learning the latter. Any idea how to do it? Can't find the solution online or help file. A dummy example:

```
library(readr)
library(data.table)
# Create dummy data
DT <- data.table(ID = 1:50,
                Code = sample(LETTERS[1:4], 50, replace = T),
                State = rep(c("Alabama","Indiana","Texas","Nevada"), 50))
# Export to csv
write_csv(DT,"test.csv")
rm(DT)
# Import
DT <- fread("test.csv", select = "ID") # col name
DT <- fread("test.csv", select = c(2)) # col index
DT <- fread("test.csv", select = c("ID") | c(2)) # both = ERROR
DT <- fread("test.csv")[c("ID") | c(2)] # Error too (NOT IDEAL since loading all data anyway)
# Dplyr's approach
DT <- read_csv("test.csv", col_select = c("ID") | c(2)) # Works!
```

Comment: I don't think this is a built-in feature of `fread`. But you could do it in 2 steps, read in just the first line, then find the columns you want, then read in the whole thing.

Comment: @GregorThomas something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207245/3585386

Comment: Huh ... I don't remember writing that, but it's what I was going to recommend :-)

Comment: Yes, so `cols <- colnames(fread("test.csv", nrows=0)) ; fread("test.csv", select=which(cols %in% "ID" | seq_along(cols) %in% 2))` does the trick (albeit not as cool-looking as `readr::read_csv`'s approach).

Answer (score 2):

A slight adaptation of https://stackoverflow.com/a/62207245/3358272:

```r
cols <- colnames(fread("test.csv", nrows=0))
cols
# [1] "ID"    "Code"  "State"
fread("test.csv", select=which(cols %in% "ID" | seq_along(cols) %in% 2))
#         ID   Code
#      <int> <char>
#   1:     1      D
#   2:     2      D
#   3:     3      B
#   4:     4      C
#   5:     5      D
#   6:     6      A
#   7:     7      C
#   8:     8      B
#   9:     9      B
#  10:    10      A
#  ---             
# 191:    41      D
# 192:    42      B
# 193:    43      D
# 194:    44      D
# 195:    45      D
# 196:    46      C
# 197:    47      D
# 198:    48      A
# 199:    49      A
# 200:    50      D
```